# how to reset dropped data when i click cancel button ? (angular material drag&drop between two table)

Tags: angular, angular7

between two table in first table to second table drop data but when i click on cancel button than how to reset table. means all changed data before submit button is reset whn i click calcel button.

```js
dropUser(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {  
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container){
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,event.container.data,event.previousIndex,event.currentIndex);

      this.uList_new_add_data = event.container.data[event.currentIndex]; //find added data
      // create array of added data
      if(this.uList_new_add_dataA.length <= 0){
        this.uList_new_add_dataA[0] = this.uList_new_add_data;
      }else{
        this.uList_new_add_dataA[this.uList_new_add_dataA.length] = this.uList_new_add_data;
      }
      //console.log(this.uList_new_add_dataA,"user list added data");
      // if it is already in this departmet
      let x = this.uList_new_add_data;
      let alldata = this.new_User;
      console.log(alldata);      
    }
  }
  // call when data droped in call
  dropCallDept(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container){
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,event.container.data,event.previousIndex,event.currentIndex);      
      this.callList_new_add_data = event.container.data[event.currentIndex]; //find added data
      // create array of added data
      if(this.callD_new_add_dataA.length <= 0){
        this.callD_new_add_dataA[0] = this.callList_new_add_data;
      }else{
        this.callD_new_add_dataA[this.callD_new_add_dataA.length] = this.callList_new_add_data;
      }
      //console.log(this.callD_new_add_dataA,"call-D added data");
      let y = this.client_Department;
      console.log(y);
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can set event.container.data = [] that will clear you list, but if you want to reset it you have to save changes inside some model and on reset just pass value.

Comment: event.container.data = []  it is note work

Comment: can you add you code on https://stackblitz.com/ it is hard to tell like this